# How can i fix Pandas DataReader Errors

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I'm trying to learn how to make a python finance app. I tried to code an app that shows me data about a stock but I got errors.
This is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

and these are the errors I get:

```
File "D:/StocksBot/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
  File "D:\StocksBot\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\StocksBot\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 376, in DataReader
    return YahooDailyReader(
  File "D:\StocksBot\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 253, in read
    df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
  File "D:\StocksBot\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\yahoo\daily.py", line 153, in _read_one_data
    resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)
  File "D:\StocksBot\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    raise RemoteDataError(msg)
pandas_datareader._utils.RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/history?period1=946692000&period2=1609552799&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message when running your code, and I checked that with curl it is possible to get that page, so the Yahoo service is ok.

I have this alternative code that works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import yfinance as yf

yf.pdr_override()

start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
df = web.get_data_yahoo('TSLA', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

This outputs the following:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Adj Close    Volume
Date                                                                       
2019-12-31  81.000000  84.258003  80.416000  83.666000  83.666000  51428500
2020-01-02  84.900002  86.139999  84.342003  86.052002  86.052002  47660500
2020-01-03  88.099998  90.800003  87.384003  88.601997  88.601997  88892500
2020-01-06  88.094002  90.311996  88.000000  90.307999  90.307999  50665000
2020-01-07  92.279999  94.325996  90.671997  93.811996  93.811996  89410500
```

Answer (score 0):

On the github page for this library, there is an issue that was opened 2 days ago where a number of people are saying that the `data_source=yahoo` has been broken since July 1.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/868